# gdalinfo gives no georeferencing information for a PostGIS raster

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgis-2.0

I have a PostGIS raster dataset which I am trying to access via GDAL. I've had various problems with making this work, so thought I'd try running the `gdalinfo` command to check that GDAL can actually make sense of the raster - and it seems to be giving very strange results.

When I run the command

```
gdalinfo  "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='testgis'
     user='postgres' password='' schema='ch13' table=kauai"
```

I get a long response which ends like:

```
 user=postgres password=  schema=ch13 table=kauai column=rast where='rid = 544'
  SUBDATASET_544_DESC=PostGIS Raster at ch13.kauai (rast), rid = 544
  SUBDATASET_545_NAME=PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testgis
 user=postgres password=  schema=ch13 table=kauai column=rast where='rid = 545'
  SUBDATASET_545_DESC=PostGIS Raster at ch13.kauai (rast), rid = 545
  SUBDATASET_546_NAME=PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testgis
 user=postgres password=  schema=ch13 table=kauai column=rast where='rid = 546'
  SUBDATASET_546_DESC=PostGIS Raster at ch13.kauai (rast), rid = 546
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Lower Right (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000)
```

(The long list of SUBDATASET lines are because my raster is tiled in PostGIS)

It seems to think that my upper left, lower left etc are all 0 - which is not correct! For example, when I run the `SELECT ST_UpperLeftX(rast) FROM ch13.kauai;` query in PostGIS I get a list of outputs like:

```
 st_upperleftx 
---------------
        418205
        420205
        422205
        424205
        426205
        428205
        430205
        432205
        432205
        434205
        436205
        438205
        440205
```

Obviously something is going wrong here, but I'm not sure what. I'm a beginner with PostGIS, so I may be doing something really silly.

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong, or what I should do next to try and debug this problem?

Comment: What version of `gdalinfo` are you using?

Comment: Gdal 1.9.0 released 2011/12/29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found the answer to this question, thanks to Bborie Park on the PostGIS-Users mailing list.

Basically, by default when communicating with PostGIS, GDAL uses a setting called `mode` with a value of `1`. This setting, called `ONE_RASTER_PER_ROW` means that each table is considered to be a collection of many different raster files, and thus you need to select a specific row to get the details on one raster.

If you set this setting manually to `2`, known as `ONE_RASTER_PER_TABLE`, it will treat the whole table as one raster file, which is the correct thing to do when rasters are tiled - as they are here.

Thus, adding a `mode=2` statement to the PostGIS connection field makes this work properly.